# How to unset layered navigation block if theres not filters inside layered navigation

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, filter, category-filter

How can I unset ***sidebar.main*** container if there's no layered navigation the layered search result page navigation if there's no filters ***catalogsearch_result_index.xml***

Comment: Hi , you can over-ride the search result page controller and unset the container directly from there.If more help needed such as in code level , please do let me know.Thanks